# tikz calendar, month label position

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I would like to make a smaller distance between month label and day headings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter%
\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
      \foreach \d/\l in {0/Ponedeljak,1/Utorak,2/Sreda,3/Četvrtak,4/Petak,5/Subota,6/Nedelja} {
        \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
        \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
        \node[every day,day heading]{\small\l};%
      } 
    }{}%
  }%
]

\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6,font=\fontsize{25}{12}\selectfont\bfseries]
\calendar (mycal) [dates=2013-05-01 to 2013-05-31,week list,month label above centered,month text=\textcolor{black}{Maj} \%y-, day yshift = 0.4cm,
         day letter headings];
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (mycal-2013-05-08) circle (5pt) +(-5pt,-5pt) rectangle +(5pt,5pt) ;
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (mycal-2013-05-10) circle (5pt);
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (mycal-2013-05-12) circle (5pt);
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (mycal-2013-05-15) circle (5pt);
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (mycal-2013-05-17) circle (5pt);
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (mycal-2013-05-19) circle (5pt);
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (mycal-2013-05-22) circle (5pt);
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (mycal-2013-05-24) circle (5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\hfill \Large legenda \\

*Napomena\hfill \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, line width=1pt] circle (6pt);
\end{tikzpicture}~~~termini

Termine je moguće iskoristiti do 8. juna.\hfill \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, line width=1pt] circle (6pt)+(-6pt,-6pt) rectangle +(6pt,6pt);
\end{tikzpicture}~~~početak/kraj termina
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `every month/.append style={yshift=-2cm}` key to the `\calendar` options as the last one, you get

[image]

```
\calendar (mycal) [dates=2013-05-01 to 2013-05-31,
                   week list,
                   month label above centered,
                   month text=\textcolor{black}{Maj} \%y-, 
                  day yshift = 0.4cm,
                  day letter headings,
                  every month/.append style={yshift=-2cm}];
```

Comment: @user28597 Welcome to the club :) My pleasure.